Coroutine return_void; difference between co_return; and falling off the end
On cppreference I read the following (emphasis mine):

Falling off the end of the coroutine is equivalent to co_return;, except that the behavior is undefined if no declarations of return_void can be found in the scope of Promise.

But clang 18.1.0 behaves differently in regards to destruction of local variables. When I fall off the end of a coroutine, the local variables get destructed, then return_value is called. When I use co_return;, return_value is called before destruction of local variables.
My question is: is cppreference making a stronger statement about co_return; vs falling off than the actual standard is? Is clangs behavior a bug, or aligned with the standard?
Here a small sample that shows the difference, along with a godbolt for your convenience:
#include <iostream>
#include <coroutine>

struct Coroutine {
    struct promise_type {
        std::suspend_never initial_suspend() { return {}; }
        std::suspend_never final_suspend() noexcept { return {}; }

        Coroutine get_return_object() { return {}; }

        void unhandled_exception(){}
        void return_void() {
            std::cout << "return_void called\n";
        }
    };
};

struct LogOnDestruct {
    ~LogOnDestruct() {
        std::cout << "Destructed\n";
    }
};

Coroutine foo() {
    LogOnDestruct logger{};
    co_await std::suspend_never{};
}
Coroutine bar() {
    LogOnDestruct logger{};
    co_return;
}

int main() {
    foo();
    bar();

    return 0;
}


https://godbolt.org/z/j75xjTf5P is your code with the prints being clear where they are coming from.

The standard is pretty clear:

If a search for the name return_void in the scope of the promise type finds any declarations, flowing off the end of a coroutine is equivalent to a co_return with no operand; otherwise flowing off the end of a coroutine results in undefined behavior.

The structure of a corotuine is such that the function body you define is effectively inside the scope of a larger function, so all of that function's local variables are in that scope. As such, a co_return exits this scope as if by a goto statement. But it only does that after calling the appropriate promise function. So the promise ought to get the function call before any local variables are destroyed.

So I'm understanding correctly that this would be a defect in clangs implementation? (as in: the correct behavior is that of explicit co_return;, the falling off behavior is a clang defect)

@wutz Well, co_return expr; should happen before local variables are destroyed (I think: otherwise, dangling stuff in expr is very dangerous), thus co_return; should mimic that, and doing nothing should mimic co_return;.
